# Excel 2013 find and replace

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, find-and-replace, localization

Excel 2013 find-replace command doesn't allow to me to replace all /, it does find them, but it can't replace them with eg ;
Whenever I try to do that, I get a message, that suggests me to add a ' before /. How can I replace all / for ; in an entire sheet? thanks advanced.

I tried that with no result. Any idea?

Comment: no Im not putting " in my replacement, I just would like to replace / with ; but excel doesn't allow me to do so

Comment: But allows it to replace the `/`'s with e.g. An `A`?

Comment: Sounds like a localization issue.

Comment: it doesn't allow me to do that either

Comment: already solved, you have to the columns where there are / as content in one step, and then the columns where there are / as formulas in another step. You can't replace both types at same time.